Motivation for twisted Yangians?
I am asking this question, hoping to understand the motivation behind the construction of the so-called twisted Yangians. This will be a long question, so my thanks in advance for any comment and/or answer.
Let me fix some notations. Firstly, everything will be over the complex numbers. Secondly, let $n \geq 1$ and let $g_n$ be a classical Lie algebra, to be thought of as a fixed point subalgebra of $gl_n$ with respect to some graph automorphism $\theta$ of the Dynkin diagram. If we thus regard $g_n[t] := g_n \otimes \mathbb{C}[t]$ as a Lie subalgebra of $gl_n[t]$ and if we endow the latter with the standard Yangian Lie bialgebra structure, then it can be shown that $g_n[t] \subset gl_n[t]$ is a Lie coideal and quantises to a coideal subalgebra $Y^{tw}(g_n)$ (the twisted Yangian in the sense of Olshanski) of the Hopf algebra $Y(gl_n)$ (the Yangian in the sense of Drinfeld).
My understanding is that when $g_n$ is of one of the types $B, C, D$, it is more "convenient" to work with $Y^{tw}(g_n)$ rather than $Y(g_n)$ for several reasons, including but certainly not limited to the following. For what follows, let $Y \in \{ Y^{tw}(g_n), Y(gl_n), Y(sl_n) \}$ and $U \in \{ U(g_n), U(gl_n), U(sl_n) \}$ (universal enveloping algebras), and let $g \in \{g_n, gl_n, sl_n\}$.

$Y^{tw}(g_n)$ is an example of a coideal subalgebra of $Y(gl_n)$, so it is useful for the theory of quantum symmetric pairs/quantisation of symmetric spaces.
If $g_n$ is of one of the types $B, C, D$, then there shall be an evaluation map:
$$ev: Y \to U$$
that "evaluates at $t = 1$" by sending the degree-$1$ generators, say $x_{i, 1}$, of $Y$ corresponding to the currents $x_i t \in g[t]$, to the elements $x_i \in U$. Thus, any $U$-module $V$ can be lifted to a $Y$-module via:
$$Y \xrightarrow[]{ev} U \to End(V)$$
Moreover, such an evaluation map does not exist for the Drinfeld Yangian Y(g_n) of types $B, C, D$.
Olshanski's centraliser construction seems to only be known for $Y$ and not $Y(g_n)$, and a recent work by Utiralova seems to indicate one should not expect there to be such a construction for $Y(g_n)$ at all. In this sense, $Y$ is more "natural" than $Y(g_n)$, at least from the POV of representation theory.

It is not clear to me, however, if the twisted Yangian is merely a technical substitute for the Drinfeld Yangian when working with the $B, C, D$ types, or was there another reason for its introduction, either coming from representation theory or physics ?
